# wordpressのsaltについて

Tags: wordpress

https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

`wp-config.php` に上記のurlで生成された値を使っているのですが、
これは定期的に(例えば1週間に1回)変えても大丈夫なものでしょうか?

大丈夫な場合、どのようなことに気をつければよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

複数のユーザで投稿作業している場合は、注意しないといけません。
入力途中でログアウトしてしまい最悪の場合　もう一度入力し直になります。

日本語版wp-config.php内コメントより、 "後でいつでも変更して、既存のすべての cookie を無効にできます。これにより、すべてのユーザーを強制的に再ログインさせることになります。"